# jQuery Pass Custom Parameter to Common .click() Handler

Tags: jquery

I have a Click-handler defined which handles clicks on an LI menu item. Suppose the code highlights the active item.

```
$('.menu li').click(function () {
   $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');   
   // etc.
}
```

On startup, I also simulate a click by calling this handler manually. This is required to highlight an item coming from a server-side URL, which will populate hidden fields. The LI Items have ID's so I manually invoke `.click()` on them.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
      if($("#queueFilter").val() == "MENU1") {
            $("#menu1").click();
      } else if($("#queueFilter").val() == "MENU2") {
            $("#menu2").click();
      } else {
            $("#menu3").click();
      }   
}
```

Problem: I need to distinguish the simulated startup `click()` invocation from the real user-initiated one. I thought of passing a custom param somehow, but it's not working. Is it possible to specify a custom handler param, which will be NULL in the other case?

Ideally what I want is, on startup:

`$("#menu1").click(false);   // Indicates a simulated click`

Then in the handler definition:

`$('.menu li').click(customarg, function () { .. }));`

A custom arg would allow me to distinguish in my handler code where I'm coming from and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.trigger` method from jQuery.  It allows to send some parameters to the event handler.

Take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

It would be like this : `$('.menu li').trigger('click', { key: value })`

Answer (score 1):

Which version of jQuery are you using?
According to the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/) you can pass any data you wish to  .click() starting from 1.4.3.
The implementation would look something like this:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
      if($("#queueFilter").val() == "MENU1") {
            $("#menu1").click({isSimulated: true}, handleMenuClick);
      } else if($("#queueFilter").val() == "MENU2") {
            $("#menu2").click({isSimulated: true}, handleMenuClick);
      } else {
            $("#menu3").click({isSimulated: true}, handleMenuClick);
      }
}

function handleMenuClick(event){
    let clickedItem = $(event.target);
    console.log(clickedItem);

    if (!!event.data && event.data.isSimulated === true) {
        console.log("Simulated click");
    } else {
        console.log("Real click");
    }

    clickedItem.siblings().removeClass('active');
    clickedItem.addClass('active');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution: use `trigger()` and `.on()` as follows,

Call the click as

`$("#menu1").trigger('click', false);`

and the handler definition is

`$('.menu li').on('click', function (e, actualUserClick) {
  ...
});`

In the case where the arg isn't passed (real user click) this arg is `undefined`.

Comment: Wouldn't you want it to be "fakeUserClick" then?  As both `false` and `undefined` are falsy, :)